# Trying to find a book with space dragons, genetically modified humans and a dual universe

Tags: story-identification, novel, dragons, genetics

When I was younger I read this Sci fi book from the library with a green hardcover surface. I remember there was an antagonist that was a human who had improved his physical abilities with Orangutan DNA. These humans were common and outnumbered pure humans, with different people choosing different animals to improve themselves with. He attacks two of the main characters in a spaceship at some point. There are also God like Space dragons. The universe is dual, with one "side" collapsed and one "side" expanded at any given time. The Big Bang is just that side expanding from the collapse of the other one. These space dragons were the only thing to escape the collapse of the previous universe. It was part of a series. Please, if anyone can help, I would be so grateful! I want to read it again as it went over my head at the time.

Comment: In roughly which year did you read this?

Comment: 2011-2013 I think.